# How to check whether an optional FeatureSet parameter was set by the user in a geoprocessing script tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, geoprocessing

I have created a custom geoprocessing script tool which contains an optional `FeatureSet` parameter.

When unpacking the parameters in the script, the `FeatureSet` is defined as a `RecordSet` object, even though no input was received. It seems to set a default value if it was not entered.

I need to check if this parameter was specified by the user or not.

For example, when I run this through ArcMap without a `FeatureSet` parameter the following occurs:

```
exportAOI = arcpy.GetParameter(3)
arcpy.AddMessage('AOI is: ' + str(exportAOI))
# AOI is: <geoprocessing record set object object at 0x14133578>
```

I was expecting `exportAOI` to be `None`.

How can I determine whether the user actually set this type of parameter?

Comment: Not played with FeatureSets much, but try checking its JSON property length or contents (e.g. compare an empty vs. a populated feature set): http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z0000005r000000

Comment: What if you use `GetParameterAsText()`? I use that for optional parameters and I just check with a simple `if not exportAOI:`

Comment: @Paul I am not sure but I believe you actually have to use GetParameter with Feature/RecordSet objects. I am not sure if they have a textual representation (other than JSON). At least the documentation does not mention using GetParameterAsText: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001n000000

Comment: I had thought about using the GetParamterAsText(), but it felt a bit hacky. I was hoping ESRI had a simple way of going about this, but I think the GetParameterAsText() is my best option at this point.

Comment: @JeremyFolds what does it return exactly?

Comment: @blah238 It returns the layer name from the TOC OR path to the input featureSet OR nothing if not given.

Comment: Can you dig through the properties of the record set object to see if there is a content or text or some other property that changes when it is assigned a value?  I don't know record set but I always check properties for .NET and JavaScript applications as a fall back.... Since it looks like an object, it should have some properties to play with.

Comment: @JeremyFolds, I feel the same way about `GetParameterAsText()` feeling hacky, but it seems to be the Esri way of doing things.  I have talked to Esri a couple of times and they always point me to using `GetParameterAsText()` over `GetParameter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, many thanks to all who commented on this. I will go ahead and answer this based on the discussion from those comments and my personal experience.

As mentioned by @blah238 and @Branco, there is a JSON property on a featureSet that can be checked, however, when running the script from within ArcMap and using a featureClass as input, checking for that property produced an error for me.

In my case, the script is being called from a GP service with a JSON FeatureSet as input, so checking against the JSON property should work, although I opted to use `GetParameterAsText()` since it should work no matter how the script is used.

In summary:

Checking if an optional featureSet parameter was actually passed in can easily be achieved by checking the existence of `GetParameterAsText()` rather than checking the existence of `GetParameter()`. Furthermore, depending on the situation, checking against the JSON property on a featureSet also works.

Thanks again to all participants!

-Jeremy

Answer (score 1):

Use the arcpy.Describe method on the featureset parameter and get the file property.

```
import arcpy

notRequiredFeatureSet = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
arcpy.AddMessage('AOI is: ' + arcpy.Describe(notRequiredFeatureSet).file)
```

if a Feature set was added:

```
    Executing: Script "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\ArcGlobeData\continent.shp"
    Start Time: Wed Jul 23 14:57:20 2014
    Running script Script...
    AOI is: continent.shp
    Completed script Script...
    Succeeded at Wed Jul 23 14:57:20 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.01 seconds)
```

If no feature set added:

```
     Executing: Script #
     Start Time: Wed Jul 23 14:54:25 2014
     Running script Script...
     AOI is: 
     Completed script Script...
     Succeeded at Wed Jul 23 14:54:25 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.00 seconds)
```

EDIT to address Paul:

```
import arcpy

notRequiredFeatureSet = arcpy.GetParameter(0)
if not arcpy.Describe(notRequiredFeatureSet).file:
    arcpy.AddMessage("No Input Received")
else:
    arcpy.AddMessage('AOI is: ' + arcpy.Describe(notRequiredFeatureSet).file)
```

Comment: How does `if not AOI` turn out I wonder?